# Can the array node be have an id?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a XML file with 6 category.  I need help to parse XML node  into PHP and have an id for each of the  node.

---catalog.xml---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Catalog>
<Category><Name>CAT1</Name></Category>
<Category><Name>CAT2</Name></Category>
<Category><Name>CAT3</Name></Category>
<Category><Name>CAT4</Name></Category>
<Category><Name>CAT5</Name></Category>
<Category><Name>CAT6</Name></Category>
</Catalog>
```

---catalog.xml---

The first node based on array would be an id [0] and subsequent [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]

When I browse it should be still CAT1, CAT2, CAT3...but their id is already created within the coding.

Many thanks.

Comment: Awesome, have you tried anything? Or did you assume we like to write free code?

Comment: Hi, I am new to php and I am working on a school project.  Have read some array coding but they are complicated.

Comment: foreach ( $catalog->Category as $category )
{
 foreach ( $category->Name as $name )
 {
 echo $name;
 }
}

Comment: You're having trouble with arrays, and you're trying to use DOM?

Comment: Please enlighten me as I am new to php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to fake it.  Just do the hard way.

---

```
<?php
$catalog = simplexml_load_file("catalog.xml");

foreach ( $catalog->Category as $category )
{
echo '<table><tbody>';

foreach ( $category->Name as $name )
{
echo '<tr>';

$menu = (string)$name;
$arr0 = "arr0.php";
$arr1 = "arr1.php";
$arr2 = "arr2.php";
$arr3 = "arr3.php";
$arr4 = "arr4.php";
$arr5 = "arr5.php";

if ( $menu == "CAT1" )
{
echo '<td background="button.png" width="200" height="60">';
echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr0\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
echo '</td>';
}
else if ( $menu == "CAT2" )
{
  echo '<td background="button.png" width="200" height="60">';
  echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr1\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
  echo '</td>';
}
else if ( $menu == "CAT3" )
{
  echo '<td background="button.png" width="200" height="60">';
  echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr2\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
  echo '</td>';
}
else if ( $menu == "CAT4" )
{
  echo '<td background="button.png" width="200" height="60">';
  echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr3\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
  echo '</td>';
}
else if ( $menu == "CAT5" )
{
  echo '<td background="button.png" width="200" height="60">';
  echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr4\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
  echo '</td>';
}
else if ( $menu == "CAT6" )
{
  echo '<td background="button.png" width="200" height="60">';
  echo '<p align=center styles="vertical-align:middle">'."<a href=\"$arr5\"><font color=#FFFFFF><strong>$menu</strong></font></a>";
  echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
 echo '</table>';

}
?>
```